# Обращение к массиву

Tags: php, json

Есть массив данных, который я извлекаю с БД

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE coin='BTC'");
$rows = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
     echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($rows);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Данные выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как обращаться к 1ому элементу подмассива ask? Т.е я хочу получить на выходе `{"price":"5613.8","amount":"11.18383683","timestamp":"1556735421.0"}`

Comment: Ну то есть вы знаете что такое json, а как работать с ним не знаете?

Comment: @u_mulder пытаюсь вывести таким образом  echo  $row['ask'][3]; но он мне выводит все посимвольно, а не целую ячейку

Comment: А декодировать джсон не пытались?

Comment: @u_mulder так echo json_decode($row['ask'][3]); вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Печально, конечно.

Comment: @u_mulder можно как-то вывести данные?

Comment: `$ask = json_decode($row[ask]); echo $ask[3];`

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите получить саму строку то думаю надо писать

```
$row['ask']
```

А если нужно достать данные из строки как массив то наверно

```
json_decode($row['ask'])
```

и в нем уже как из массива доставать данные

Answer (score 0):

Используйте true как второй аргумент для json_decode -- тогда вернётся ассоц.массив.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php